# SQL query, a JOIN and a COUNT and a DISTINCT

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.user_login 
FROM wp_posts AS a JOIN wp_users AS b 
WHERE a.post_author = b.ID AND a.post_type = 'tee';
```

This outputs what I need, it shows me the user's name.
However, I'd also like to COUNT how many times this occurred next to the user_login.

Help and explanation much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: A JOIN, a COUNT, and a DISTINCT / All in a query, succinct. / Aggregation was needed, / The OP sadly pleaded. / Answer came before OP even blinked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` aggregate:

```
Select  b.user_login, 
        Count(*) As cnt
From    wp_posts AS a 
Join    wp_users AS b   On  a.post_author = b.ID
Where   a.post_type = 'tee'
Group By b.user_login;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use COUNT(DISTINCT [fieldname]).  This will provide a count of unique non-null values present in [fieldname].